# How to active custom css of wordpress option tree?

Tags: wordpress

I want add custom style using wordpress option tree. I create dynamic.css file. But when I input any style in option tree that do not work.

If input style in `dynamic.css` file directly then style is execute. But I want use option tree for style. What can do now?

Can you tell me the full process of this?

Comment: I have tried just any css style in option tree like changing background color, font size, etc. for example footer:{background:red;}